# Broadcast message in OnConnectedAsync

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

How do I broadcast a message as soon as a client connects? I have tried using Clients.All.SendAsync in OnConnectedAsync but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. I do this in a few of my hubs. There may be an issue with the way you have set up the OnConnectedAsync method perhaps? Maybe you could share what your hub and client look like?

Mine looks something like this:

```
    public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // do work with database regarding user who just connected

        // Send connection id of user who just connected to all clients
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserConnected", Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Looks the same. With that said, will the message be seen by the client that just connected?

Comment: @Rob Yes the client that just connected should receive the message. Are you perhaps setting up the connection 'channel listeners' after you start the connection? Starting the connection should be the last thing you do after specifying what 'channels' to listen on. When I say 'channel listeners' I mean when you define things like connection.on("UserConnected"). Perhaps you can share what your client looks like if you still face issues?

Comment: Duh...I completely overlooked the fact that my handler was set after the connection was made.

Thank you.